# No operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, iostream

Need help figuring out what's the issue with the following source code. I've got a single class to count a number of characters and display each one of them into the console screen.

But unfortunately i kept getting this error message when i tried compiling

> error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

The following are the source files:

**CharacterCounter.h**

```
 #include <iostream>

 class CharacterCounter {
    public: 
      int fTotalNumberOfCharacters;
      int fCharacterCounts[256];  // hold all 256 byte values 

    public: 
      CharacterCounter();
      void count(unsigned char aCharacter);
      friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& aOStream, CharacterCounter& aCharacterCounter); 
    };

   }
```

**CharacterCounter.cpp**

```
    #include "CharacterCounter.h"
    #include <iostream>

    /// Constructor 
    CharacterCounter::CharacterCounter() {
      fTotalNumberOfCharacters = 0;
      for (int i=0; i < 256; i++) {
          fCharacterCounts[i] = i;
      } 
    }

    /// Counts the corresponding data member 
    void CharacterCounter::count(unsigned char aCharacter) {
      fTotalNumberOfCharacters++;
      fCharacterCounts[aCharacter]++;
    }

    /// Output stream displays characters greater than 0 
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& aOStream, const CharacterCounter& aCharacterCounter) {
      for (int i=0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (aCharacterCounter.fCharacterCounts[i] > 0) {
          int character = aCharacterCounter.fCharacterCounts[i]; 
          aOStream << (unsigned char)i << ":\t" << character << "\n"; 
        }
      } 

      return aOStream;
    }
```

**Main.cpp**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include "CharacterCounter.h"

    using namespace std; 

    int main() {

      CharacterCounter counter; 
      unsigned char character;

    while (cin >> counter) { **Compilation error focuses here**
       counter.count(character);
    }

    cout << counter; 
    system("pause");

    return 0;
   };
```

Comment: You have `operator<<`, not `operator>>`.

Comment: The parameter for `CharacterCounter` should be `const`.

Comment: You're defining `operator <<` (output) for the class, but using `>>` (input) in `main`. Can you explain why you think this should work? Or did you actually intend to write `while (cin >> character)` instead of `while (cin >> counter)`?

Comment: By the way, your initialization of `fCharacterCounts` is probably not correct. I assume you would want all of the elements to be *zero*? Use [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill), [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) or even [`std::memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) to "clear" the array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Our lecturer provided the assignment without suggesting to anything to us if we should ass override operator>>, and by the way once we override operator>> is it a must to override the other operator as well ?

Comment: If you only want output, then *overload* only `operator<<`. If you want only input then overload only `operator>>`. If you want both output and input, overload both. There are no rules or "standard that says one must implement both.

Comment: @Angew I think you might be right cause i was expecting a value from the console, let me try fix that part and see if it works.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload operator `>>` for your `CharacterCounter`, because of `cin >> counter`, declare it:

```
class CharacterCounter {
    public: 
//...
      friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, CharacterCounter& aCharacterCounter);
//...
```

And then declare function overload:

```
std::istream &operator>>( std::istream  &input, CharacterCounter& aCharacterCounter ) 
{ 
    input >> aCharacterCounter. fTotalNumberOfCharacters;
    // Or input something else or more
    return input;            
}
```